# python ошибка вывода списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

написал файл-конфиг для программы:

```py
items = {
    1: ['img/1.jpg','word1','123','1'],
    2: ['img/2.jpg','word2','1222','1'],
    3: ['img/3.jpg','word3','31231','1'],
    4: ['img/4.jpg','word4','123131232','1'],
    5: ['img/5.png','word5','1231312222','1']
}
```

но при обращении к элементу словаря возникает ошибка:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.items[x][0]'

Comment: добавьте код, который показывает как вы пытаетесь обратиться и импортировать данный конфиг

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если внимательно прочитать ошибку (а с этого всегда и нужно начинать, а не бежать сразу за помощью в интернет), то можно увидеть, что там написано:

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.items[x][0]'**

Это означает, что файл с именем `config.items[x][0]` не найден. И ведь действительно, я уверен, что этот файл называется не `config.items[x][0]`.

Решение: разобраться с тем, что там файл конфигурации, что там словарь и не путать одно с другим.

Answer (score 0):

Если конфиг был файлом с расширением `.py`, то при использовании такого обращения всё должно быть нормально. Значит проблема или с `x`, или с импортом.

Comment: что это значит? что такое `x`? дайте более развернутый ответ